# CSDL format to JSON

Tags: arrays, node.js, json

How can I transform the data received in CSDL format from an Oracle DB to JSON format in NODE JS

```
 export async function  getRecepFarma(req: Request, res: Response): Promise<Response> {
  const conn = await connect();
  const result = await conn.execute(
  `SELECT * FROM IVMOV`
 )

 return res.json(result);
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wo1dP.png)

Answer (score 0):

The driver is not returning CSDL format unless that's just a coincidence. The driver returns a JavaScript object with properties, such as `metadata` (with info about the columns) and `rows` (the actual data).

The easiest way to convert a JavaScript object to JSON is with `JSON.stringify(object)`. However, you're calling [res.json](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.json), which will do this for you. If you just want to send the data as JSON, you can call `return res.json(result.rows);`.

The resulting JSON will be an array of arrays by default. However, if you want an array of objects, then you can the `outFormat` property, either at the global level (`oracledb`) or as an `execute` option.

Here's your code modified to do that:

```
export async function  getRecepFarma(req: Request, res: Response): Promise<Response> {
  const conn = await connect();
  const result = await conn.execute(
  `SELECT * FROM IVMOV`,
  [], // no binds
  {
    outFormat: oralcedb.OUT_FORMAT_OBJECT
  }
 )

 return res.json(result);
}
```

If you want to stream a large result set, rather than use the buffered `rows` property, then that does take just a little more code. Let me know if that's something you need.

Finally, you might find this series on creating a REST API with Node.js and Oracle Database useful: 
https://jsao.io/2018/03/creating-a-rest-api-with-node-js-and-oracle-database/